# What's the best way to keep track of ActiveRecord's i18n validation messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization

I'm constantly forgetting to translate things like `activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.name.blank` in all my app's languages. Does anyone have any advice for keeping track of where translations are missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is set `I18n.config.exception_handler = :raise_i18n_exception` in your test environment. It won't catch everything but it's super easy and better than nothing.

(In config/environments/test.rb it'd be just `I18n.exception_handler = :raise_i18n_exception`
)

Comment: All the answers were super helpful! But this one answered my question most directly. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Gettext is de-facto standard in translations. Its very feature-rich and frankly I hate apps trying to reinvent wheel. Thats why I always switch to gettext-rails (or fastgettext) plugins.

It works well with Models: http://www.yotabanana.com/hiki/ruby-gettext-howto-rails.html#Models

And ... it solves your problem. Gettext can help you keeping track of untranslated strings - you can configure to scream on you or just return the untranslated string (default).

Comment: Sorry to say, but it seems like that project is incredibly outdated... A lot of people say Rails's I18n has replaced its functionality.

Comment: Outdated gettext?!? Replaced gettext? That's not true: https://github.com/grosser/fast_gettext and more info here: http://ruby-i18n.org/wiki

Comment: Ah! Sorry, was looking at https://github.com/mutoh/gettext_rails -- I'll check out fast_gettext.

Comment: My fault, I linked wrong project (the old one). Although it does not answer your question, it could solve your problem. Gettext is really used everywhere in open-source...

Comment: Hmm I don't quite understand the difference between gettext and Rails's native I18n functionality...

Comment: Mmmm this does not solve @Aaron's problem: he is asking about ActiveRecord I18n, and gettext is an alternative solution to using rails i18n. Secondly the gettext does not handle the Activerecord messages at all: https://github.com/grosser/fast_gettext/wiki/activerecord

Comment: In the original answer I did recommend gettext in general. There are many gettext rails plugins, e.g. this one handles it: gettext_i18n_rails = solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [translate](https://github.com/mynewsdesk/translate) plugin that adds a little web management console for your translation keys (and shows you which keys are missing and where).

It's probably a bit old but works with Rails 2 and should work even with 3 if you're up to the task of fixing some config issues (or just picking up the pull request that's already available in there).

Answer (score 1):

Sometime ago I was thinking to a simple way to share all common translations across all apps. This [railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends) gave me an idea on how to do that.

In short you can chain different translation backends and i18n gem will use them in the defined order, so I was thinking to use a Redis backend* to store all common translations (such as AR validation messages) and use that as a fallback backend for all my apps which need i18n.

This approach could solve your issue taking it from another point of view: write translations once and share them forever. Moreover any time you found a missing translation you'll fix it for all the apps which use the shared backend.

I haven't implemented this yet because I had no time to do that, but my idea was to do something like the mentioned [translate interface](https://github.com/mynewsdesk/translate) to manage translations and share them using the approach shown in the railscast.

Hope this will help.

*[Redis](http://redis.io/) or any other persistent network key-values store would be ok for that task.